# What is the proper way to insert known values into a VS 2010 Database project post-deployment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I've tried a few different google searches but can't find any best practices or tutorials that address this.

This is the first time I've used a VS database project. I've imported an existing database (everything looks fine) and now I want to populate some of the tables post-deployment.

There is a `Script.PostDeployment.sql` file that includes the following header:

```
/*
Post-Deployment Script Template                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 This file contains SQL statements that will be appended to the build script.       
 Use SQLCMD syntax to include a file in the post-deployment script.         
 Example:      :r .\myfile.sql                              
 Use SQLCMD syntax to reference a variable in the post-deployment script.       
  Example:      :setvar TableName MyTable                           
           SELECT * FROM [$(TableName)]                 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
```

I'm wondering if from the last three lines there is some expected way to write these scripts using variables instead of just pure T-SQL syntax?

Should I be writing

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BlackAdder] VALUES ('edmund')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BlackAdder] VALUES ('baldrick')
```

or

```
setvar [dbo].[BlackAdder] BlackAdder
INSERT INTO [$(BlackAdder)] VALUES ('edmund')
INSERT INTO [$(BlackAdder)] VALUES ('baldrick')
```

Does the latter allow some sort of compile-time check so that if `setvar` cannot resolve `[dbo].[BlackAdder]` that the project will give me some error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the project `Properties` folder, and click on `Database.sqlcmvars` you will see 3 vars already defined `$(DefaultDataPath),` `$(DtabaseName)` and `$(DefaultLogPath)` and can define your own here.

The setvar would be the other way around:

```
:setvar BlackAdder [dbo].[BlackAdder]
```

but ideally you define these in `Database.sqlcmvars`.

The intended use is for deploying your database project into multiple environments by defining SQLCMD variables and including them in your pre-deployment and post-deployment scripts.

- [How to: Define Variables for Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386162.aspx)
- [Property Files in Database and Server Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193289.aspx)

Comment: Oh, ok. So variables have nothing to do with verifying that the tables exist before trying to write data in post-deployment to them. I guess I could ask that as a different question :)